# How to get parent tag?

Tags: regex, node.js

I am using Node.js to handle text with regex.  I have the following strings

```
 <span class="ls8">,  <span class="ls8">respiration<span class="ls8">, and
 </span><span class="ls8">photosynthesis<span class="ls8">. At least </span>
 </span></span></span></div>
```

Here i am trying the following Regex, but did not get parent tags

```
 <span class="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/span>
```

Close span is not getting at end.   But it catches first close span.

How to get parent span?

Any one assist me to handle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `.*` instead of `.*?`.. but avoid parsing `HTML` with regex

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with Regex!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5743988) Use the DOM or an (HT|X)ML parser.

Comment: You really should use something like the `cheerio` module to properly parse HTML instead of using regular expressions.